# Why is my new lawn bumpy and how can I address it?

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair

I laid a new small lawn which will be 2 years old this summer. I put a lot of work and new soil into getting it flat and level and I'm pretty happy with it aesthetically.

It's mostly for show but I've noticed when you sit on it, it's pretty uncomfortable - lots of small bumps maybe about golf-ball sort of size.
It wasn't like this when I prepared the ground or after laying the turf so what has happened, and what/when is the best option to get it smoother here in Northern England?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you done some digging to find out what the bumps actually are? (Btw, your lawn looks very nice!)

Comment: Is your soil quite stoney?